# Why does component remount every state update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

EDIT:

I made some stupid mistakes within my code prior to asking this question. I realise now that this question likely will not serve as useful to anyone as what I am saying is actually in itself misleading. Apologies and thank you to those that replied.

---

I am currently learning React Native and have come across some unintuitive behaviour. As far as I am aware, the useEffect hook can be used in such a way to determine the life-cycle of a component (i.e. when it mounts and dismounts). When I update the state within a component (in this case 'ComponentX'), the entire component seems to remount. I did not think that this was the intended behaviour. If someone could tell me if it is so - or what I am doing wrong that is causing this to happen - that would be very helpful! Thanks.

**Expected behaviour**: Component does not unmount and remount.

**Actual behaviour**: Component remounts on every state change.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableHighlight, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ComponentX />
  );
}

const ComponentX = () => {
  const [componentState, setComponentState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted");
    return () => console.log("unmounted");
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red", padding: 20 }}
        onPress={() => {
          setComponentState(componentState + 1);
        }}
      >
        <Text>Update State</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text>{componentState}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: If you also log the value of `componentState` in the `useEffect` (without updating the dependency array) what does it show?

Comment: This appears to be an insufficient code example to produce any component remounting. Are you saying that `ComponentX` is being unmounted and remounted? What is remounting it in `App`? Double check your code to see if you've added an `useEffect` dependency on `componentState` that is causing your effect callback to be called each time `componentState` is updated as this would cause multiple `"mounted"` logs to occur.

Answer (score 1):

It is an intended behaviour.

While a React component can have initial state, the real power is in updating its state — after all, if we didn't need to update the state, the component shouldn't have any state. State is only reserved for data that changes in our component and is visible in the UI.

Instead of directly modifying the state using this.state, we use this.setState(). This is a function available to all React components that use state, and allows us to let React know that the component state has changed. This way the component knows it should re-render, because its state has changed and its UI will most likely also change.

If you want the component not to re-render, please try React.memo()

hope this helps: https://linguinecode.com/post/prevent-re-renders-react-functional-components-react-memo

or try

1. PureComponent instead of Component

or

2. Use shouldComponentUpdate - The shouldComponentUpdate method allows us to exit the complex react update life cycle to avoid calling it again and again on every re-render. ... Return value: It by default it returns true and if it returns false then render(), componentWillUpdate() and componentDidUpdate() method does not gets invoked.

Answer (score -1):

any time if you change/update state, related component will be render and mount again.
this is the intended behaviour

Comment: When a state changes, it only rerenders and preserves others states.
The state resets only on mont/unmount.